# How to get Database items into a list with ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I cant seem to get the URL's in a simple list which I can show on a page. I already have the connection with the database in another project within my solution and that works for sure. only problem is putting the data into a list.

URLController

```
public class URLController : Controller
{      
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        LinkHubDbEntities db = new LinkHubDbEntities();
        ViewBag.UrlList = new SelectList(db.tbl_Url.OrderBy(c => c.UrlId), "UrlTitle", "UrlDesc");

        return View();
    }
}
```

The view :

```
@model BOL.tbl_Url

@{
ViewBag.Title = "List";
}

<ul>

@foreach (var UrlId in ViewBag.UrlList)
{
    <li>@tbl_Url.UrlTitle</li>
}

</ul>
```

Comment: Looks like there are some very basic fundamentals which are wrong

Comment: Okay, I don't like the ViewBag and I don't like a lot of other things but.... intellisense should provide you with @Model.UrlTitle instead of the weird thing you've got at the moment.  Try that.  If it doesn't work I'll post some code which will work properly and have a better structure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279547/how-to-display-database-records-in-asp-net-mvc-view do a simple google search come on @MikeLammers

Comment: whats the @tbl_Url inside the for loop? the URLList is in your viewbag and not model.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do something like this:

Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
        {
            ViewBag.ProcessList = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.ProcessList)
    {
        <li>@item.ProcessName</li>
    }
</ul>
```