# How do I display a record of database in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I m working with asp.net with MVC code-first approaches.

In my database, 4 records and I want to display record but a record not display?

table name:empls

[image]

How can I get records of database and display on the brows

**HomeController.cs**

```cs
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        EmpContext contextemp = new EmpContext();
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM empls";

            var model = new List<Student>();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cn))  //error //can not convert from system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection to string
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    var student = new Student();
                    student.empname = (rdr["empname"].ToString());
                    student.empsalary = (rdr["empsalary"].ToString());
                    student.empage = (rdr["empage"].ToString()); // error cannot implicit type object to string

                    model.Add(student);
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```cs
@model IEnumerable<DemoMvcInUpDecodefirstapproach.Models.Student>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.empname)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.empsalary)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.empage)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
           @item.empname
        </td>
        <td>
          @item.empsalary
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.empage
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}


</table>
```

**Context class:**

```cs
  public class EmpContext : DbContext
    {
        public EmpContext():base("conn")
        {

        }

        public virtual DbSet<Student> stud { get; set; }
    }
```

**Student class:**

```cs
namespace DemoMvcInUpDecodefirstapproach.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        [Key]
        public int empidid { get; set; }

        public string empname { get; set; }

        public string empsalary { get; set; }

        public string empage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

What I m missing in the above program?

when I m debugging my programme then my debugger never checks foreach loop instead of index.cshtml?? so that is issue bind the data from the database.??still try?

Comment: Are you getting any values in here: `contextemp.stud.ToList()` ? Also try printing out values without using DisplayFor template: `@item.empname,@item.empsalary,@item.empage`

Comment: @RahulSharma I edit your suggestion but still not solve the problem check my index.cshtml(for each loop) i edited my index.cshtml

Comment: Are you getting any values in your List from the database? Have you tried debugging and see what do you get in :`contextemp.stud.ToList()`

Comment: @RahulSharma sir thanks for the suggestion, I tried debugging ```c# count=0```  shows still try??

Comment: Yes exactly, you need to figure out why you are not getting any values from the database. Trying changing your `DbSet` to: `public virtual DbSet<Student> empls{ get; set; }` and then in your Controller: `contextemp.empls.ToList()`

Comment: @RahulSharma, when I m debugging, my debugger never checks for each loop instead, which means my foreach loop is not working in index.cshtml so data is not bind from the database?? still, try??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203670/discussion-between-ran-nusarat-and-rahul-sharma).

Comment: Why are you creating two connections to the database?  You comment that you get an error in the while(), what are you doing to handle that?

Comment: Your entity has a different name to the database table it is supposed to point to. Try adding annotation `[Table("empls")]` to Student's class, that's for the Rahul's suggestion to returns something. As Duston said you are creating two connections. Just use the context `contextemp`, it allows you to run raw sql queries as well.

Comment: @RahulSharma sir,  thanks solve the issue

Comment: @A.J.  sir, thanks solve the issue

Comment: @RahulSharma ```c#  [Table("empls")]
    public class emp
    {}```    add this annotation on the class

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@Html.DisplayFor` instead of displaying the data directly.

Example :

```
@model IEnumerable<DemoMvcInUpDecodefirstapproach.Models.Student>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.empname)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.empsalary)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.empage)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.empname)
        </td>
        <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.empsalary)
        </td>
        <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.empage)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Hope it'll work for you.